# Server path of VHD drive

Tags: c#, azure-storage

I want to get the server path of VHD drive. I am working on azure web application. I have some files uploaded and saved it in to the Test.VHD drive (say). This is a cloud drive inside some blob container "drives" (say). I mounted and mapped it by following way:

```
driveLetter = drive.Mount(localCache.MaximumSizeInMegabytes - 20, DriveMountOptions.Force);
```

"driveLetter" is "A:\" (say). Now I am displaying all the pdf file names as link buttons on the page. On click of those files I want to open that pdf file in the browser by using the javascript function

```
window.open(pdfPath, pdfName, 'scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes');
```

**My question is what do I have to pass as a "pdfPath" parameter?**

I have the path "A:\Uploads\pdfName.pdf". But I can't pass it. I have to pass it like http://servername:port/path so that user can view it.

But I don't know how to convert it to the link like http://servername:port/path. By doing this I can view the pdf in the browser.

Please help me,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this doesn't directly answer your question, but... I think you're going to see some limitations in what you're doing by writing to Azure Drives:

- Only one Role instance, at any given time, can have write access to the vhd. This means your solution scale beyond one instance unless you have a unique vhd per instance (or each add'l instance simply makes a read-only snapshot)
- You now have to go through your Role instance to access individual files, as you cannot provide a direct link to a file inside a vhd to the outside world
- To manage any file, you have to have an Azure Drive mounted. This means you can't manage any files from code outside of Windows Azure (Azure Drives are only mountable by Windows Azure Role instances)

I'd suggest writing individual files to individual blobs. This has several advantages over using Azure Drives in your scenario:

- Any instance can read/write each individual file (each file in a separate blob)
- You have the choice of embedding direct file url's in your web pages. This provides direct access to a blob without having to route through one of your Role instances (which, in turn, takes load off said instance since IIS isn't needed)
- You can choose to make individual blobs private, and *still* provide url's to private blobs, via Shared Access Signatures
- You can manage individual blobs remotely, and there are several 3rd-party tools available to help you do this.
- If you wanted to, you could enable CDN (edge caching) for your storage, which then lets you point your URL's to a CDN link instead of directly to the source blob. This is limited to public-facing blobs.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!! I did whatever you have suggested. I left the solution of VHD and started using blobs with blob container. Thanks to all for all your help!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a small confusion there.

An azure drive is technically a blob stored in Azure Blob Storage, so it has a URL. In contrast, the CONTENTS of an Azure drive is not directly accessible using URLs. If you want to expose the files contained in the Azure drive, you have to make them accessible from your windows Azure instance.

You can do this by mapping your Azure drive as a virtual folder in IIS when you mount the drive. If you code in .Net, have a look at System.Web.Administration (you'll have to include it in your project, it's part of IIS and not directly in the CLR). If you code in another language, the simplest way is to call appcmd.exe to define the virtual folder.

Pierre

Comment: It is accessible. My Test.VHD is my blob. I have mounted it as "A:\". A: has some pdf inside it so how shall I access this pdf using some link locally as well as on azure server.